# How can I determine the correct voltage connector in an addressable LED strip?

Tags: led, rgb, pc

I found a couple of cheap Addressable RGB strips laying around and they seem to have a different connector that won't fit in the current PC ARGB controller.

I cannot identify what type of ARGB module on each LED, but there are 3 wires on that strip. Since they're addressable, I assume they're 5 V.

Is there a way to determine which is the voltage wire and ground wire without plugging into the controller? I wanted to avoid burning it, which I have done in the past. I used this [cheapo multimeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvw1i.png) to determine something, but to no avail.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: figure out what sort of addressable LEDs are installed and then use the multimeter to figure out what wire goes where.

Comment: A photo might help.